# тестовая страница  Apache вместо сайта

Tags: apache, apache2

Всем привет подскажите что делать если вместо сайта test.ru отображается тестовая страница Apache. а вместо www.test.ru она вообще недаступна.пробывал набирать https://www.test.ru, браузер выдает что страница недаступнапрописал вроде всё правильноhttpd.conf    AllowOverride All #  Options NoneOptions Indexes FollowSymLinks    Order allow,deny        Allow from all    # Virtual hostsInclude conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.confhttpd-vhosts    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.localhost        DocumentRoot "C:/www/test.ru/www"        ServerName test.ru        ServerAlias www.test.ru        ErrorLog "C:/www/test.ru/logs/error.log"        CustomLog "C:/www/test.ru/logs/access.log" common    ip тоже прописалчто ещё нужно?![alt text][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYw54.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поправьте httpd.conf:

> <Directory "C:/www/test.ru/">

Там должен быть прописан полный путь до вашего сайта. В никсах можно использовать в этой директиве и регулярные выражения, а в вендах не пробовал, не знаю.